# Custom UITabBarController selectedController

Tags: ios

I have a custom UITabBarController and it has several view controllers added as relationship segues. I want to find out which view controller I am selecting. I am handling the

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {


        guard let controller = self.selectedViewController else {
            fatalError("No controller selected")
        }


        // but controller always come as UIViewController and not strongly typed controller 


    }
```

Comment: Use type(of: `self.selectedViewController`) to determine whats the type of the `UIViewController`.

Comment: There is no method named type?

Comment: It doesn't auto populate. I don't know why. You can use it. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html

Answer (score 0):

Just implement this delegate in your tabbarcontroller. you can get the segue name from here, assign to a global variable and you're all set.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

}
```

Comment: Prepare for segue is not fired for the relationship view controllers.

Comment: The other easy way is to use singleton and have a variable "curentController" in it. And then, at viewdidappear of each VC, set the variable to the VC's name.